# Setup Firebase Remote Config

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I want to use **Remote Config** in a application **Xamarin.Forms**.
I use a blog -  [Firebase Remote Config in Xamarin Forms](https://mookiefumi.com/2019-12-17-firebase-remote-config-in-xamarin-forms)

I have a question about the section: **Setup Firebase Remote Config**.

### **Quote**

> We can setup Firebase Remote Config through the Firebase portal https://console.firebase.google.com/project/Your-Firebase-Project/config and it is an easy process because the portal GUI is nice and friendly. To do it, we add a new parameter key and the default value and of course it can be a json (the GUI has a tool to validate the format of the json content). In the example case the key will be Features and the default value a json:
>
> ```json
>     {
>         "ShowPlayerDetail": false
>     }
> ```
>
> In this case, we setup a key called ShowPlayerDetail to show or not the player detail.

---

### **Question:**

Where is the `JSON` file referred to in this section?

### **Note.**

I am currently in a project.

[image]

---

### **Update-1**

[image]

---

---

### **Update-2**

[image]

---

---

### **Update-3**

[image]

---

---

### **Update-4**

[image]

---

---

### **Update-5**

I have completed the following steps.
Did I do the right thing?
Do my actions correspond to what is described in the blog?

Or do I need to perform **Publish changes**? (see **Pic-4. Result**)

---

**Pic-1**
[image]

---

**Pic-2**
[image]

---

**Pic-3**
[image]

---

**Pic-4.  Result**
[image]

Comment: Go to setting of project in firebase. There you will find JSON file.

Comment: @Unwanted Coder Are you talking about this?
See the picture **Update-1**

Comment: Absolutely Yes.

Comment: @UnwantedCoder 
I can't find this file.
I see the file in `Rules`. See `Update-2`
Is that him?

Comment: Please see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBn5w.png

Comment: @UnwantedCoder See `Update-4`.
What should I do?

Comment: @Unwanted Coder 
Maybe you need to do as I did in `Update-5`.
Did I do the right thing?
Have I done what is required in the blog?

Comment: @Unwanted Coder Or do I need to perform **Publish changes**? (see **Pic-4. Result**)

Comment: You are doing right. But first you have to upload your app on firebase.

Comment: Checkout this guide to implement Firebase Remote Config in Android using Kotlin
https://androidacademic.blogspot.com/2024/01/firebase-remote-config-android.html

Answer (score 0):

You're using an existing Firebase project but there are no apps in your project, please see the Update-4 screenshot .

You could click the iOS or Android icon to [add app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) to your Firebase project, and make sure the Apple bundle ID matches the Bundle identifier in info.plist of your Xamarin.iOS project, the Android package name matches the packagename in AndroidManifest.xml of your Xamarin.Android project. After registering the app, you can download the  google-services.json file for Android and the GoogleService-Info.plist file for iOS.